# EditorFor and ValidateFor on a List in PartialView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

After selecting a value in a drop down list, I have a partial view being created. This partial view is based on the following ViewModel :

```
    public class vm_ElevesCoursNotes
    {
        public List<Models.ELEVE> eleves { get; set; }
        public Models.COURS cours { get; set; }
        public List<Models.NOTER> notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Models.NOTER is based on this Model :

```
    [Table("NOTER")]
    public partial class NOTER
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDNOTER { get; set; }
        public int IDELEVE { get; set; }
        public int IDCOURS { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{1}([.][0-9]{1})?$", ErrorMessage = "bad grade format")]
        public float NOTE { get; set; }
        public short NUMERO_NOTE { get; set; }
        public virtual COURS COURS { get; set; }
        public virtual ELEVE ELEVE { get; set; }
    }
```

Inside my partial view, I want to add @Html.EditorFor the field NOTE for each item of the List notes.

I tried the following method after browsing a lot of topics :

```
    @model pwanSprint1.ViewModels.vm_ElevesCoursNotes
    @using (Html.BeginForm("validerNotes", "GestionNotes", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "lstEleves"))
    {
        foreach(var note in Model.notes)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(note => note.NOTE)
            @Html.ValidateFor(note => note.NOTE)
        }
    }
```

For the moment I wrote some HTML code and tried to do some client side custom jQuery validation but nothing seem to work.

The objective is to list students from a certain class and all the grades they have. I should also be able to insert data where the grades are not filled yet. Something like the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKwwK.png).

What am I doing wrong ? Is there something simple I don't understand ?

PS : I'm a complete beginner in MVC, sorry.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop. You need a `for` loop of custom `EditorTemplate` to generate forms controls for a collection. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: try with 
`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(note => note.NOTE)`